# Using generalized estimating equations to model outcomes with a population offset

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `gee` to model counts of an outcome with a population offset.I have models with interaction terms and am trying to use the all effects package to summarize parameter estimates and odds ratios (ORs).

When I compute ORs by hand, I'm not sure why its not matching the output I get from the `effects::allEffects()` function. The data can't be shared but the model is

```r
mdl <- geeglm(count~age+gender+age:gender+offset(log(totalpop)),
          family="poisson", corstr="exchangeable", id=geo, 
          waves=year, data=df)
```

I use the below code to compute stuff manually. `log_OR` sums the interaction terms without intercepts added to parameter. `log_odds` sums the parameters with intercept. The code is taken from [here](https://yury-zablotski.netlify.app/post/multiple-logistic-regression-with-interactions/).

```
tibble(
  variables      = names(coef(mdl)),
  log_OR = c(...),
  
  log_odds = c(...),
    
  OR = exp(log_OR),
  odds = exp(log_odds),
  probability = odds / (1 + odds)
) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~round(., 5)) %>%
  knitr::kable()
```

I then compare my manual calculations to the output of allEffects below. They don't match. Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong?

```
result <- allEffects(mdl) 

allEffects(mdl) %>% summary()

variable <- result[["age:gender"]][["x"]]
Prob <- result$`age:gender`$fit
Prob_upper <- result$`age:gender`$upper
Prob_lower <- result$`age:gender`$lower

model_Est <- data.frame("Est"=Prob, "CI Lower"= Prob_lower, 
                        "CI Upper"= Prob_upper)
model_Prob <- exp(model_Est)

model_est <- data.frame("Variable"=variable, model_est)
model_OR <- data.frame("Variable"=variable, model_OR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us very much to go on, but the cause is almost certainly that the offset isn't being dealt with properly. (The first thing I would try is running the model without the offset to see if the results from `effects` and your by-hand calculations match: that's not the model you want, but it will confirm that the problem is with the offsets.)

`?effects` says:

> `offset` a function to be applied to the offset values (if
> there is an offset) in a linear or generalized linear
> model, or a mixed-effects model fit by ‘lmer’ or ‘glmer’;
> or a numeric value, to which the offset will be set. The
> default is the ‘mean’ function, and thus the offset will
> be set to its mean; in the case of ‘"svyglm"’ objects,
> the default is to use the survey-design weighted mean.
> ***Note:* Only offsets defined by the ‘offset’ argument to
> ‘lm’, ‘glm’, ‘svyglm’, ‘lmer’, or ‘glmer’ will be handled
> correctly; use of the ‘offset’ function in the model
> formula is not supported**.

(emphasis added)

`methods("effects")` lists only `effects.glm` and `effects.lm`, which suggests that the model is being treated as a `glm` (i.e., there is no specialized method for GEE models). So, this suggests:

(1) you need to include `offset=` as a separate argument in your model.

(2) when doing your hand calculation, make sure the value of the offset is set to the mean value across all observations (unless you choose to use the `offset=` argument to `effects`/`allEffects` to change the default summary function).